# using npx create-react-app my-app come up with an error

Tags: node.js, npm

using npx create-react-app my-app but come up with an error.

npm : 6.4.1
node : 11.3.0
how to fix this?

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "Files\nodejs\node_cache\_npx\6612" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_cache\_logs\2019-07-13T04_25_44_642Z-d
ebug.log
Install for create-react-app@latest failed with code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, Running npx globally does not work on windows when the user folder patch contains a space.see this [link](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/146)